# Prevention of Lashon Hara as a protection for military wars

Tags: army-military-war, lashon-hara-slander

In light of the current situation in Israel, one of the calls that has been made is specifically to try and cut down on Lashon Hara.

I have seen two similar sources concerning the generation of Achav:

[Devarim Rabbah 5:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.5.10?lang=bi)

> תֵּדַע לְךָ דְּאָמַר רַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָן דּוֹרוֹ שֶׁל אַחְאָב עוֹבְדֵי עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים הָיוּ וְהָיוּ יוֹצְאִין לַמִּלְחָמָה וְנוֹצְחִין, וְלָמָּה כֵן, שֶׁלֹא הָיָה בֵּינֵיהֶן דֵּילָטוֹרִין, לְפִיכָךְ הָיוּ יוֹצְאִין לַמִּלְחָמָה וְנוֹצְחִין
>
> You should know, that Rabbi Shmuel bar Nachman said: Achav's generation were pagan worshippers, yet they went out to war and won. Why was this so? Because they did not have informers (a negative term suggesting that they denounced others) amongst them. Therefore, they went out to war and won.

[Yerushalmi Peah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Peah.1.1.46?vhe=Mechon-Mamre&lang=bi)

> אמר רבי אבא בר כהנא דורו של דוד כולם צדיקים היו וע"י שהיה להן דילטורים היו יוצאים במלחמה והיו נופלים...אבל דורו של אחאב עובדי ע"ז היו וע"י שלא היה להן דילטורין היו יורדים למלחמה ונוצחין
>
> Rabbi Abbah son of Kahana said, the generation of Dovid were all righteous, but because there were informers among them, they went to war and were falling...But the generation of Achav who were idol worshippers did not have informers, descended to war and were triumphant.

How does specifically not speaking lashon hara act as a protection?

Is it literally the case, that when a person speaks lashon hara it creates a קָטֵיגוֹר (a prosecutor) in shamayim (heaven) against that person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Yaaros Devash, Drush 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Yaarot_Devash_I.15.10?vhe=Yaarot_Devash_--_OYW&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains how it works, and starts by bringing the midrash cited in the question:

> בדורו של שאול היו צדיקים אלא שהיו בעלי לשון הרע ולא הצליחו במלחמה אבל בדורו של אחאב היו בעלי עבירה ועבודה זרה רק לא היו בעלי לשון הרע ולכך הלכו במלחמה ונצחו וא"כ א"ש דאמר לו מפיבושת לא עליך אני כועס כי אתה באת בשלום וא"כ הוכחת דע"כ לא קבלת לה"ר דאל"כ לא היית מצליח במלחמה דזהו עונש לה"ר להיות נופל בחרב מלחמה אמנם על מי אני כועס על מי שהביאך בשלום דהוא יודע כי באמת קבלת לה"ר וא"כ לא היה לו להצליח כעונש בעל לה"ר ראו כמה גדול עון לה"ר אפילו בעלי עבירות כדורו של אחאב לא היה דבר שהיה להרשיע המלחמה כי אם לשון הרע ו**הטעם כי בהסתת הנחש היה נעשה להט חרב המתהפכת לרוע ולטוב ולכך בשומרם עקב רב מבלי לעשות ואינם בעלי לשון הרע ואז חרב נהפכת עליהם לטובה לעשות באויביהם נקמה ואם תפשו מעשה נחש אזי החרב נהפכת לרעה לעשות בהם כלייה ולכך נצחון המלחמה תלוי בלשון הרע וכל השומר פיו מלשון הרע כובש החרב המתהפכת ולכך נאמר (תהלים קמט ו) רוממות אל בגרונם וחרב פיפיות בידם לעשות נקמה כו'** וכבר אמרו כל דיבור שיוצא מפי אדם עושה רושם ובעו"ה אדם מפטפט כל היום בדברים ואינו מרגיש שבכל דבר עושה רושם עד שאמרו חז"ל (סנהדרין קב ע"ב וכן במו"ק י"ח) **ברית כרותה לשפתים** ואיך לא ישמור אדם מבטא שפתיו על כל דבר פשע
>
> In the generation of Shaul they were righteous but they spoke lashon hara and were not successful in war, but the generation of Achav were sinners and idol worshippers however they did not speak lashon hara and therefore they went to war and were successful. Indeed, didn't Mefiboshes say, "I am not angry with you because you came in peace, and if so, you have proven that you did not accept slander, because if not, you would not have succeeded in the war since this is the punishment for slander - to fall by the sword of war. However, who am I angry with? The one who brought you in peace, since he knows the truth about accepting slander, and if so, he would not have succeeded as a punishment for slander, see how great the sin of lashon hara is, even for those who are sinners like the generation of Achav, there was nothing to condemn the war other than lashon hara. **And the reason is that by inciting the snake (i.e. speaking lashon hara), a sword would become flaming that turns to evil and good, And for this reason, their safekeeping has a lot to do without doing it; and if they are not slanderous - then the sword turns to good for them to take revenge on their enemies, and if they caught the act of a snake (i.e. they speak lashon hara), then the sword turns to evil to wreak destruction, and thus the victory of the war depends on lashon hara, and anyone who guards his mouth from lashon hara conquers the overturned sword and this is why it is said ([Tehillim 149:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.149.6?lang=bi)) "The lofty praises of G-d are in their throats, and a double-edged sword in their hand to execute vengeance etc."** And they have already said that every word that comes out of a person's mouth makes an impression. And nowadays a person chatters all day about things and does not feel that he is making an impression in anything - until the sages said ([Sanhedrin 102a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.102a.2?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) and similarly [Moed Kattan 18a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.18a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - **"A covenant is made from the lips" (i.e. what one say impacts on future events)** and how can a person not keep his lips from uttering anything sinful?!...

So, it appears from Rav Yehonasan Eibshitz that the act of saying lashon hara effectively sways the balance of war. If G-d decrees that one side is due to succeed but lashon hara is spoken, then the "sword" of war, so to speak, reverses and has the opposite effect. We can't underestimate the power of words, especially as he brings from Chazal, that it can huge ramifications in future events. (See further there where he brings that not speaking lashon hara was one of the reasons why the Bnei Yisroel were redeemed from Egypt).

Comment: The Rav brings up your point about Egypt (and many other evocative examples of how important Shemirat Halashon is) in this video and he also brings the idea that the Satan can't prosecute people who don't speak LH: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMZ5X9k-INM

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a source for this, and this is perhaps more of a practical answer than a spiritual one, but lashon hara is particularly divisive - it creates hatred and distrust between people and sinas chinam, which is the opposite of what we need, especially during a war.  Soldiers require trust in each other to function effectively as a unit/army, and to feel very positive about the nation who they are defending to have the motivation to put their lives on the line to save others.

What we're seeing now is a sudden reduction in sinas chinam and a massive improvement of ahavas chinam and achdus.  The sad thing is that it has taken an event like this for us to achieve it, but I do think that it is middah k'neged middah in a way as we were attacking each other and now we have been attacked.  IY"H this improvement in our behaviour will be a merit for success in rescuing the captives, utterly destroying our enemies and achieving a lasting peace, and that this should be a permanent change rather than us going back to fighting internally when things calm down again.

Comment: +1 - logical assessment thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rav Elyeh Lopian zl [(Lev Eliyahu Volume ויקרא page 48) (Otzar HaChochmah)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/642273/p/56/t/0.176685320824080951234/fs/2LvZgF3C2AWR5uVk7Yll6YbTOsaH8pcY7JHMUXPWxBXQ/start/0/end/21/c) explains that in heaven they'll deal with us in the same way that we deal with our fellowmen here below.  If we speak bad about each other, then in heaven the prosecuting angels will be allowed to do the same. If, however, we don't slander/accuse each other down here, up there the angels won't have permission to speak bad about us.

Here are his words:

> והיינו כיון שהם לא קטרגו על חבריהם, ושמרו את פיהם למטה בארץ, לכן מדה
> כנגד מדה לא היה בכח שום מקטרג לקטרג עליהם למעלה, וממילא נתקיים בהם לא
> הביט און ביעקב ולא ראה עמל בישראל, כאמור למעלה, והיו יורדים למלחמה
>
> ומסיימים חז"ל במד"ר, שבדורו של שאול כולן היו דילטורין, לפיכך היו
> נופלים במלחמה וכר ע"ש, והיינו ג"כ כמו שאמרנו, שאם יש לשה"ר וקטרוג
> בישראל למטה, נעשה גם קטרוג בשמים, ומדת הדין מתוחה עליהם, והרי נעשה
> חורבן גם למעלה כאמור, וזהו שתו בשמים פיהם ולשונם תהלך בארץ, נמצא המספר
> לשה"ר על חבירו חוטא גם בשמים וגם בארץ

Comment: The sefer is on Otzar HaChochmah (Parashas Kedoshim, p. 48). But, does this deal specifically with warfare?

Comment: I know it is on Otzar hachochma (I took the quote from there) but one can't make a direct link to it, as one could to Sefaria or Hebrewbooks. He quotes and explains the Medrash Devarim Rabba which Dov, the questioner quoted, and which refers to warfare.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Would that show the page to people who don't have Otzar Hachochmah?

Comment: Thank you very much. I keep on discovering more and more. Will try it out later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149180/discussion-between-imanonov-and-shmuel).

Answer (score 0):

The introduction to the Sefer Chafetz Chaim brings the point that Hashem judges *midda k'negged midda*, and therefore when we speak Lashon Hara, the Satan is allowed to become a *mekatreg* against us and accuse us in the heavenly court. The heavenly court is tied to do justice, and therefore our sins receive judgements to the "full extent of the law", and therefore that's why Lashon Hara opens the door to harsh decrees.

When we don't speak Lashon Hara, the Satan doesn't speak against us in heaven. Therefore, Hashem Himself judges our sins, and He doesn't have to "answer to the court" and invokes His mercy, which will involve waiting, or only invoking the decrees our property rather than ourselves, or giving us *kapara* very slowly over time and in easy ways.

**tl;dr** The best strategy to protecting ourselves from the harsh decrees of the heavenly court against our sins is to prevent the prosecution from even speaking against us, which is accomplished by us not speaking LH. HaRav Shimon Kessin explains in [this shiur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMZ5X9k-INM) that gaining *zechuyot* by taking on *tefilla* and *mitzvot* are amazingly helpful (for protection), but not nearly as helpful *shemirat halashon*, because the former helps us in court, the later *cancels court*.

Of course, both are vital! Especially because the *mitzvot* and *tefillot* do much more than protect us.